# Store value in variable by using DoCmd Object in MS access

Tags: ms-access, vba

Dear Expert I am trying to store value in variable by using DoCmd Object, but i am getting error that is **Expected Function or Variable**.

Please find my below VBA code.

```
Set chk = DoCmd.FindRecord("sagar", acAnywhere, True, acSearchAll, False, acAll, True)
```

Comment: `FindRecord` doesn't return a value. I carries about the *Find* action in the database (like the CTRL+F Find window).  You haven't given enough information to indicate how you're trying to use this command. I'd suggest starting with Googling examples of the command being used, and then [edit] your question to add more information and example of what *specifically* you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

`FindRecord` doesn't return any values, you cannot assign results to variable. Not clear what does it mean `chk` in your code, but if you execute `DoCmd.FindRecord` first, this will move current record to the target row, then you'll be able to get/set values in record columns, delete the row or continue to search.

Comment: This isn't much of an answer;  if you think you know the OP's problem, could you please expand on this a little, perhaps adding relevant tlinks and some code showing how to solve the issue?  (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7693/370758))